# Tornado: how to spawn two requests and process results as they are done

Tags: python, tornado

I am a little lost with Tornado and could use some advice about which way to tackle a problem I am trying to solve.  While handling a request, I need to make two calls out to other services and process the results and return to the client as the requests are done rather than waiting for them all to complete.  The first result that meets my needs will get returned to the caller.

I have been reading up on tornado.gen, coroutines and futures and am very confused about what will work for this.  I do see that I will need to use tornado.gen.WaitIterator() to get the results of futures as they finish.  I am not sure how to make the two external requests and how to put it all together.

Comment: It is unclear what you want. The part with `...return to the client as the requests are done rather than waiting for them all to complete.` seems to be conflicting.

Comment: Oh, ok.  I receive a request from a client and then, in that callback, I need to make two asynchronous calls in parallel to other services before returning. When I receive a reply back from one of the services, I need to reply back to the original client without waiting for the second external request to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from tornado import gen, httpclient

async def foo():
    client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
    waiter = gen.WaitIterator(client.fetch(url1), client.fetch(url2))
    async for resp in waiter:
        # Do something with resp.
        # waiter.current_index tells you which request this is.
```

If you only want to process the first result, you can `return` or `break` from inside the `async for` loop (although sometimes this spams the logs about futures that were started but never awaited).

There are more examples in [WaitIterator's docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html#tornado.gen.WaitIterator)

Comment: Thanks.  Will this work as well with python 2.7 that does not support the async and async for keywords?

Comment: Yes, you can use `waiter.done()` and `waiter.next()` in older versions of python. There's an example of this in the linked docs.

Comment: Thanks, Ben.  This will get it working for me.  I have a followup question if you don't mind.  I will be calling to the same two sites over and over and would like to take advantage of http/1.1 persistent connections for performance.  I assume that from your example, the AsyncHTTPClient will be created each time foo() is called and the connection will closed when foo() returns.  Would I be better served by using a ThreadPoolExecutor to reuse the same AsyncHTTPClient?

Comment: It's not helpful to use a ThreadPoolExecutor with asynchronous code. AsyncHTTPClient has some magic to ensure it reuses existing objects. However, the default implementation does not currently support connection reuse so you'll need to configure it to use curl_httpclient.

Comment: I got this working but did not experience log spamming from futures started but not awaited.  I log a message in on_finish and then see one of my client.fetch() return after on_finish completes.  Will this cause any issues?

Comment: Should be fine. I think the log spam problem is just on python 3.5, where `async def` functions have a special check to see if they've been abandoned.

Comment: I have been running this for a while now with python 2.7 and a waititerator. I am having a memory leak that is very noticeable now that the server is being hit hard.  Could it be from having outstanding httpclient requests after my requesthandler is gone?